# Count number of unchanged values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of survey responses. I'm trying to see how many questions were answered the same way in a row.

```
#Data
s <- structure(list(Student_ID = c("1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
"1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
"1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
"1234", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", 
"5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", 
"5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678", "5678"), key = c("Q1.1", 
"Q1.2", "Q1.3", "Q1.4", "Q1.5", "Q1.6", "Q1.7", "Q1.8", "Q1.9", 
"Q2.1", "Q2.2", "Q2.3", "Q2.4", "Q2.5", "Q2.6", "Q2.7", "Q2.8", 
"Q2.9", "Q2.10", "Q2.11", "Q2.12", "Q1.1", "Q1.2", "Q1.3", "Q1.4", 
"Q1.5", "Q1.6", "Q1.7", "Q1.8", "Q1.9", "Q2.1", "Q2.2", "Q2.3", 
"Q2.4", "Q2.5", "Q2.6", "Q2.7", "Q2.8", "Q2.9", "Q2.10", "Q2.11", 
"Q2.12"), value = c(4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 8, 4, 5, 7, 5, 6, 
8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), .Names = c("Student_ID", 
"key", "value"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've tried this:

```
s %>% group_by(Student_ID) %>% mutate(strip = ifelse(value != lag(value,1,default = -1),1,0)) %>% print(n = 100)
```

which correctly identifies the places where I should start counting (with a 0). I tried to use this:

```
s %>% group_by(Student_ID) %>% mutate(strip = ifelse(value != lag(value,1,default = -1),1,lag(strip)+1)) %>% print(n = 100)
```

but receive an error that the object 'strip' cannot be found.

Here's what I'd like to see:

```
#Answer column
s$answer <- c(rep(1,19),2,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Comment: Here is one option with `data.table` `setDT(s)[, answer := seq_len(.N), .(cumsum(value != shift(value, fill = -1)), Student_ID)][]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by grouping them into consecutive streaks using `cumsum`, then using `row_number()` to find the index within each group:

```
s %>%
  group_by(Student_ID) %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(value != lag(value, default = -1)), add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(answer = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```